# Trouble Taking Receving Array from other Class Into Method Without Re-Prompting

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, methods

Having a really hard time with this problem. I've tried searching to find a similar situation but I can't seem to find anything that helps. I feel like I've got it 99% of the way and it's probably something very simple but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

I have two classes. ClassA and Restaurant.

The problem is that in my method call for printRestaurant() in the main method of ClassA, some of the methods need to receive the array with restaurant names but when I use the methods, it reprompts for the restaurant names each time it hits the next method instead of only prompting once and then moving to execute the next method.

ClassA:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ClassA
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ownerName = "";

    System.out.printf("%nWhat is the name of the owner?");
    ownerName = input.nextLine();
    Restaurant rest = new Restaurant(ownerName);
    rest.arraySize();
    rest.printRestaurant(ownerName,rest.setRestaurants(),rest.setCustomers(rest.setRestaurants()),rest.calcAvgDailyRev(rest.setRestaurants()));

    input.close();
    System.exit(0);

  }//END main()

}//END Application Class ClassA
```

Restaurants:

```
public class Restaurant
{
  //Fields
  String ownerName = "";
  int size = 0;
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  public Restaurant()
  {

  }//END Restaurant()

  public Restaurant(String name)
  {
  ownerName = name;
  }//END Restaurant(String ownerName)  

  public void arraySize()
  {
    System.out.printf("%n%s, how many restaurants do you own?  ",ownerName);
    size = input.nextInt();
  }//END arraySize()

  public String[] setRestaurants()
  {
    String[] restNames = new String[size];

          input.nextLine(); // clears buffer
    for(int row = 0;row < restNames.length; row++)
    {

      System.out.printf("%nEnter restaurant %d",row+1);
      restNames[row] = input.nextLine();

    }//END for col < restNames.length

    return restNames;

  }//END setRestaurants()

  public int[] setCustomers(String array[])
  {
    int[] noCustomers = new int[size];
    for(int i = 0;i<noCustomers.length;i++)
    {
    System.out.printf("%nEnter the average number of daily customers for %s: ",array[i]);
    noCustomers[i] = input.nextInt();
    }//END for i < size
    return noCustomers;
  }//END setCustomers()

  public double[] calcAvgDailyRev(String array[])
  {
    double[] avgBill = new double[size];
    input.nextLine(); //Clears buffer

    for(int i = 0;i<avgBill.length;i++)
    {
      System.out.printf("%nEnter the average bill for %s: ",array[i]);
      avgBill[i] = input.nextDouble();

    }//end for i < size
    return avgBill;

  }//END calcAvgDailyRev(String array)

  public void printRestaurant(String name, String restName[], int customers[], double dailyAvg[])
  {
    System.out.printf("%n%n%S's RESTAURANTS",name);


    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
      double avgRevenue = customers[i]*dailyAvg[i];

      System.out.printf("%n%nRestaurant:  %s"
                       +"%nAverage No of Daily Customers: %d"
                       +"%nAverage Bill Per Customer:  $%,.2f"
                       +"%nAverage Daily Revenue:  $%,.2f",restName[i],customers[i],dailyAvg[i],avgRevenue);
    }//END for i < size

  }//END printRestaurant()







}//END Restaurant
```

Here is an example of the desired output:

What is the name of the owner?  Cliff
Cliff, how many restaurants do you own? 2
Enter restaurant 1: Eggs
Enter restaurant 2: Bacon
Enter the average number of daily customers for Eggs:  250
Enter the average number of daily customers for Bacon: 200
Enter the average bill per customer for Eggs: 12
Enter the average bill per customer for Bacon: 15

CLIFF’s RESTAURANT

Restaurant: Eggs
Average No of Daily Customers: 250
Average Bill per Customer: $12.00
Average Daily Revenue: $3,000.00

Restaurant: Bacon
Average No of Daily Customers: 200
Average Bill per Customer: $15.00
Average Daily Revenue: $3,000.00

If you need any additional information please let me know. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: I would start off by removing *all* aspects of user input from your `Restaurant` class. Make that *solely* the responsibility of your "driver" class. It doesn't sound like a `Restaurant` class should have a `size` field at all, which would be the *number* of `Restaurant` objects you want instantiate... Basically, think about your object model again. It looks like a `Restaurant` object should have a name, a number of customers, and a daily revenue. Those make sense as fields in the `Restaurant` class, not things you pass into a `printRestaurant` method.

Comment: Jon - thank you very much for your feedback. I completely agree which is the main reason I'm having so much trouble with this ask. The instructions specifically ask us to use this logic however or I would change it drastically.

Comment: They really specify *that* design? That prescriptively? I would personally *at least* follow up with whoever is setting this and complain that setting assignments using awful designs is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the value returned by the method. But here you are calling the method, and as per the method definition is prompting for input.
So, instead of calling the method, again and again, you can save the return type and use whereever needed.
e.g.

```
    String restName[] = rest.setRestaurants();
    int numberOfCust[] = rest.setCustomers(restName);
    double dailAvgRev[] = rest.calcAvgDailyRev(restName);
```

You can use theses values restName, numberOfCust,dailAvgRev to print Restaurant information.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked like magic. I knew I needed to get the info from the arrays, not the methods but could not figure out how to do so. Seems simple looking at it now....VERY much appreciated user2044822!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is you don't have a while loop in your main method. So the nextLine() will get executed only once without going back to the scanning routine. You can also define a special string such as "quit" to indicate you want to quit the scanning process.

Try the following maybe? :D

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class ClassA {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String ownerName = "";

            System.out.printf("%nWhat is the name of the owner?");

            while (!(ownerName = input.nextLine()).equals("quit")) {
                Restaurant rest = new Restaurant(ownerName);
                rest.arraySize();
                ...
            }

            input.close();
            System.exit(0);

        }//END main()

    }//END Application Class ClassA
```

It will keep prompting until you enter the string "quit". Hope it helps.